# How to calculate age into years, month, day with js (using js ui datepicker)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I am very beginner in **JS**.I can calculate age in years with below code.This code is working perfectly for years calculation.If i put date after 12 ***(ex. 14/12/1950)*** of any month then its showing **NaN** Years.Now i want to display *Years,Months,Days* of age from anyone's given birthday.Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 console.log($(document).width());           
     $('#datepicker').datepicker
    ({
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: '1900:2150',
        maxDate: new Date(),
        inline: true,

             onSelect: function() {
               var birthDay = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
                var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
                var today = new Date();
                var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
                age = Math.floor(age / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));

                document.getElementById('agecal').innerText = age;
            }
     });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="datepicker">Date of Birth: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Date of Birth...">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="agecal">Age as On(<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>): <span id="agecal" style="background-color:#60ab59;padding: 0px 50px 0px 50px;color: white;font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;" >0</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out the problem. Firstly, `NaN` returns because of two date format was not same. Now I converted it into `mm/dd/yy` from `dd/mm/yy` after that i get the months and days with `getMonth()` and `getDay()` respectively.

```js
$(document).ready(function () 
{
 console.log($(document).width());           
     $('#datepicker').datepicker
    ({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        yearRange: "-100:+0",
        maxDate: new Date(),
        inline: true,

             onSelect: function() {
               var birthDay = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
                var DOB = new Date(birthDay);
                var today = new Date();
                var age = today.getTime() - DOB.getTime();
                var elapsed = new Date(age);
                var year = elapsed.getYear()-70;
                var month = elapsed.getMonth();
                var day = elapsed.getDay();
                var ageTotal = year + " Years," + month + " Months," + day + " Days";

                document.getElementById('agecal').innerText = ageTotal;

            }
     });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="datepicker">Date of Birth: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date_of_birth" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert your Date of Birth...">
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:10px;">
  <label for="agecal">Age as On(<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>): <span id="agecal" style="background-color:#60ab59;padding: 3px 15px 3px 15px;color: white;font-weight: bold; border-radius: 5px;" >0 Years,0 Months,0 Days</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a small fiddle with your code and was able to get the difference in the following way:

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/suvartheec/zrhpmrgs/2/

Explanation: I created a new date variable using the milliseconds that you are getting by subtracting the two times(now and b'day). that gives us a date relative to Jan 1970 (because that date is calculated as time elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, with leap seconds ignored. source:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
So I subtracted 70 and am getting the number of years.

```
        var elapsed = new Date(age);
        document.getElementById('agecal').innerText = elapsed.getYear()-70;
```

Its a rough idea but that should get you going.

EDIT: Updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/suvartheec/zrhpmrgs/3/

The cause of NaN for dates greater than 12 is the inherent date format in JS is mm/dd/yy. changing your datepicker config to send the date in that format takes care of that. Either that or you have to translate it in the onSelect function to get it to a form that would be compatible with the rest of the codes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have two issue but you didn't give the answer of these two issue.
**1.** I want age as  in `years,months,days`. **2.** When i give after 12 `(ex. 15/12/1960)` date its showing `NaN`.

Comment: Updated answer for the "date after 12" issue. For the other one (get months etc) you can use the getMonth and other function on the elapsed variable to get that data.